# How do you format the output of printing count

Tags: arrays, perl, printing, count, format

The following code gives the result of

```
Female4946Male5054gender1
```

How do I add spaces between the element and its number and why is it printing the array with a 1 next to it?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @gender;
my $female=0;

while (<>) {
    chomp;
    my @fields = split /,/;
    push @gender, $fields[5];
}

my %count;
$count{$_}++ for @gender;
print %count;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have a header line in your input file that contains `gender` as a column title and that is read and counted once. Skip the first line by reading a single line from the filehandle into void.

```
<>;
```

To insert a space between every pair (but not after the last pair!) use `join`. The code block for `map` will build the string for each pair:

```
print join " ", map {"$_: " . $count{$_} } keys %count;
print "\n";
```

Or more nicely (from my point of view) with newlines between them:

```
while( my ($gender => $count) = each %count) {
    print "$gender: $count\n";
}
```

Comment: Hashes don't interpolate in double quotes.

Comment: You're right. I should not have posted that. Removed the respective block.

Comment: @DanielBöhmer How would I get them to print on the same line but with the spaces between them?

Comment: As you probably now `\n` stands for a newline. You can move these in the code or add/remove some and adapt the output to your like. It's not too complicated, I think. For your convenience I updated my answer again.

Comment: @DanielBöhmer Doing it by your updated answer gives me "Female  4946Male  5054" How do I get a space between 4946 and Male while keeping them on the same line

Comment: Add a space to the print statement.

Answer (score 2):

You are not printing an array, you are printing a hash. Use a loop to print it (you may hide it into a `map`). Also, why do you populate the @gender array, when you can create the hash directly?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %count;

while (<>) {
    chomp;
    my @fields = split /,/;
    $count{ $fields[5] }++;
}

for my $gender (keys %count) {
    print $gender, ' ', $count{$gender}, "\n";
}
```

The `1` at the end comes from a line that hash `gender` in its sixth column (a header maybe?) You can `delete $count{gender}` before printing it, or add a `<>` before the while loop to skip the header.

Comment: Please explain *"You are not printing an array, you are printing a hash"*. The OP didn't mention arrays or hashes anywhere. And I hope it is obvious how the intermediate use of `@gender` clarifies the code.

Comment: @Borodin: `print %count` is *printing a hash*, while the question mentions *printing the array* (starts at position 145).

Answer (score 1):

All you need is

```
print join(' ', %count), "\n"
```

**output**

```
Female 4946 Male 5054 gender 1
```